# OutofMemory Exception on new Bitmap()

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework

I have to draw something on a Image wich is captured by the Camera. This works on many Devices, but sometimes the RAM is too small or the pictures too big and the function crashed with a OutOfMemory Exception.

How am I able to:
a) optimize the code to prevent this Exceptions
b) Handle this Exceptions (making pictures smaller, free Ram etc.

here is the code:

```
 Dim from_bmp As Bitmap
 Dim bmp As Bitmap

 from_bmp = New Bitmap(picname)
 'I also tryed this with a function which is creating the Bitmap from Filestream
 'I also tryed this with the OpenNETCF.Drawing.Imaging.IImage
 'If the Original Pictiure is too big, the function will crash here.

 bmp = New Bitmap(from_bmp.Width, from_bmp.Height + stampheight)
 'now I Create a bitmap which is higher than the original, in order to write the stamp beneth the picture

 Dim font As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Regular)
 gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
 gr.DrawImage(from_bmp, 0, 0)
 from_bmp.Dispose()
 'here I draw somethin in the Bitmap
 bmp.Save(deststring, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
 gr.Dispose()
 bmp.Dispose()
```

Comment: Upgrading your system memory is the best bet

Comment: @Gens That exception usually comes on many platform, not only Windows, not only .NET.

Comment: this is net.cf, the code is running on mobile devices, I'm not able to upgrade the Memorya of them ^^

Comment: How big is the image (w x h) and what is it's color depth?

Comment: this depends on the camerasettings of the device, i use this function on 1800 mobile devices and round about 20 different types. Ist's running well for years, but The Problem occurs very often on the new Motorola ES400. The Images on this device are (in the smallest case) 1024*1380 px, 192 dpi, 24 Bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd likely use a "using" pattern for your Bitmaps.  Also, be aware that an OOM on Bitmap creation can often be overcome by simply trying again ([here's a diatribe](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2006/08/22/BitmapsInTheCompactFramework.aspx) as to why).  My bet is that the GC Heap is too full and a second request, especially after a collection, would succeed.

I'd go through the rest of the code (that not shown) and make sure that all other graphics objects are getting properly Disposed - the CF doesn't handle auto clean-up of the native resources of graphic objects very well and often needs a bit of help (again, see the above link).

Comment: yes, I shoud have mention that, i perform a GC.collect(), i dispose every Bitmaps I uses and in the catch block I try it again after GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers